# WebPartPage title

Tags: 2013, web-part-page

I've created a webpartpage and for some reason the title of the page is set to the filename of the page, not the `Title` column.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour and know of a fix?

Comment: check this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16838/change-page-title-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE. I'm using BPOS environments, and don't have permission to use SPD. I ended up using a jQuery workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for why this is occurring so I ended up implementing a workaround. A couple of limitations:

1. SharePoint 2013 Online (i.e. No SPD)
2. No deployed code

My workaround makes use of jQuery

```
function SetTitle (newTitle){
    var $title = $('#pageTitle > span > span');

    if ($title){
        $title.text(newTitle);       // attempt to set the SharePoint page title
        document.title = newTitle;   // change the Window/Tab title
    }
}
```